# Is there a feature extraction method that is scale invariant but not rotation invariant?

Tags: computer-vision

Is there a feature extraction method that is scale invariant but not rotation invariant? I would like to match similar images that have been scaled but not rotated...

EDIT: Let me rephrase. How can I check whether an image is a scaled version (or close to) of an original?

Answer (score 0):

Histogram and Gauss Pyramids are used for extract scale invariant features.

> How can I check whether an image is a scaled version (or close to) of an original?

It's puzzle for me. Does you mean given two images, one is original and another is scaled? Or is one original and another is a fragment from the original but scaled and you want to locate the fragment in the original one?

---

[updated]
Given two images, *a* and *b*,

1. Detected their SIFT or SURF feature points and descriptions.
2. Get the corresponding regions between *a* and *b*. If none, return false. Refer to [Pattern Matching - Find reference object in second image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623431/pattern-matching-find-reference-object-in-second-image-opencv) and [Trying to match two images using sift in OpenCv, but too many matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017031/trying-to-match-two-images-using-sift-in-opencv-but-too-many-matches). Name the region in *a* as *Ra*, and one in *b* as *Rb*.
3. Using algorithm like [template match](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) to determine if *Ra* is identical enough to *Rb*. If yes, calculate the scale ratio.

Comment: Hi. I really would like to know, what kind of ideas we can apply for the later part where the fragment is given with scaling, can you please share your thoughts.