# Whether the SIFT is rotation invariant feature or not opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to write a code in opencv that proves whether the SIFT is rotation invariant feature or not.
Assuming that the image has one keypoint which is the center of the image. I want to caculate keypoint descriptor (magnitude and direction). I want to ask what is the keypoint ? is it a location in the image ? 
I searched for simple tutorial or code to know what to do but I didn't find something simple.

Answer (score 2):

A keypoint is an interesting point in your image. These points are usually found when you have a change in intensity, for example, at the edges between two objects in the image. A keypoint encodes, among other things, the location of the point in the image. SIFT will then extract a local feature descriptor for your keypoint which you can then use for image matching.

Scale Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT) is scale invariant, as the acronym says. It is not rotationally invariant. In such a case, you could use SURF. But, SURF is a little problematic for real-time applications.

SIFT: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform

SURF: http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/papers.html

Example code: [Trying to match two images using sift in OpenCv, but too many matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017031/trying-to-match-two-images-using-sift-in-opencv-but-too-many-matches?rq=1)

To test your SIFT code out, you could create a black 512x512 image in Opencv with three equally spaced white colored points along its width. Then, rotate the image by small rotations angles, measure the angle, and check the feature matches. As you are doing this, you will realize that for large rotations, the features matches are thrown off.